# Django UpdateView using the validation of a custom create view

Tags: django, django-views, django-generic-views, django-validation

SOLVED: Read Daniel Roseman's neat answer. It worked perfectly.

I am not a very expert on Django: sorry if my question has a trivial answer.
I am using Django dev (1.8?).
My application manages the entries of certain `DATE` type which needs to be validated and coherent. Therefore in

```
views/create_fest.py
```

I have as follows:

```
class Formulario_nuevo_festivo(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Festivo
    fields = ('nombre_festivo','fecha_unica','fecha_inicio','fecha_fin')
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data=super(Formulario_nuevo_festivo,self).clean()
    fecha_unica     =cleaned_data.get("fecha_unica","")
    fecha_inicio    =cleaned_data.get("fecha_inicio","")
    fecha_fin       =cleaned_data.get("fecha_fin","")
    if fecha_unica and fecha_inicio and fecha_fin:
        raise forms.ValidationError(u"some message")
    elif not fecha_unica and not fecha_inicio and not fecha_fin:
        raise forms.ValidationError(u"some message")
    elif (fecha_unica and (fecha_inicio!=None or fecha_fin!=None)) or (fecha_inicio and not fecha_fin) or (fecha_fin and not fecha_inicio):
        raise forms.ValidationError(u"some message.")
    else:
        if (fecha_unica and (fecha_inicio==None or fecha_fin==None)):
            pass
        elif fecha_inicio > fecha_fin or fecha_inicio==fecha_fin:
            raise forms.ValidationError(u"some message.")
        else:
            pass
    return cleaned_data

def page(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = Formulario_nuevo_festivo(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('listado_festivos'))
        else:
            return render(request, 'crear_festivo.html',{'form':form})
    else:
        form=Formulario_nuevo_festivo()
        return render(request,'crear_festivo.html',{'form':form})
```

which works perfectly: the validation works fine and the user can only create an object by accomplishing with the validation-
The problem comes when i am using UPDATEVIEW to manage changes to this model:
Here comes a piece of code inside of `views.py` snippet:

```
...
class FestivoUpdateView(UpdateView):
model           = Festivo
fields          = ['nombre_festivo','fecha_unica','fecha_inicio','fecha_fin']
template_name   = "editar_festivo.html"
success_url     = reverse_lazy('listado_festivos')
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if "cancel" in request.POST:
        self.object = self.get_object()
        url = self.get_success_url()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
        return super(FestivoUpdateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
...
```

The thing is that the user can enter whatever data into this UdateView with no kind of validation.

I have searched a lot (since I am not an english native speaker) but i am not having luck on finding an answer.
A lazy programmer would say "hey you could repeat the validation code in the views.py and do the validation again" but it would be against DRY philosophy and i am pretty sure there must be an easy way to force the UpdateView to use the create view validation.

What about if i put it someplace like "core/validate.py" and then import it as a function?
I have no clue how to solute this, any help would be appreciate.
 Thanks ahead

Comment: Don't use the dev version. Stick to the stable 1.7 release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to tell your view to [use your form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_class).

```
class FestivoUpdateView(UpdateView):
    form_class = Formulario_nuevo_festivo
    ...etc...
```

Note there doesn't seem to be anything in your form that makes it solely for *new* festivals, so you may want to rename it to something more generic (and PEP8-compliant), such as FormularioFestivo.

Comment: Thanks for answering so fast, and so concise. 
Daaamn! The solution seems so obvious...indeed i come across that before on the search on the docs...but my import didnt worked out. Anyways i will try again tomorrow.
You mean to change from Formulario_nuevo_festivo to FormularioFestivo?
:)

Comment: SOLVED! Thanks Daniel.